# UITableView content overlaps Status Bar when UISearchBar is active

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uicontainerview

I have a UITableViewController with a UISearchBar and UISearchDisplayController. That exists inside a Container View in a UIViewController which is in a UINavigationController. I made this image to help describe the structure:

[image]

This is what it really looks like:

[image]

When I tap the Search Bar, I have to hide the Nav Bar. Normally, this would happen on its own, but since my UITableViewController is inside a Container View, I have to handle that change myself. This is what it looks like then, note that the Status Bar is white because the Nav Bar is white, even though it is Hidden at the moment.

[image]

Once I start typing in some search text, the results show up. If I scroll those results upward, they pass underneath the Search Bar, but they overlap the Status bar which is very unattractive.

[image]

If the Container View isn't involved, then this all works as intended and the table content passes underneath the Status Bar, but with the ContainerView involved, the table text and status bar collide.

How do I get the text to travel under the Status Bar like normal?

Answer (score 37):

I have search this for hours and my final result was to put this line in viewDidLoad:
    `self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;`

Problem solved :)

Comment: this really helped even though I had a different problem! My problem was that I couldn't control the background colour of the status bar when the search bar was active. Thank you

Comment: Just for someone who comes across this.

Make sure to add the ```self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES``` in the containerViewController and the searchResultsViewController.

Comment: You can also do this from the view controller's attributes inspector in the storyboard (check Extend Edges -> Under Opaque Bars)

Comment: definesPresentationContext = true and self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true fixed it for me!

Answer (score 5):

Try setting the `definesPresentationContext` in `viewDidLoad` of your `TableViewController`

Swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    definesPresentationContext = true
}
```

Objective-C

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's what worked for me:

DO:

- Use UISearchController (not a separately placed UISearchBar)
- Place your VC in a UINavigationController if it isn't already. Set the nav not to "Show Navigation Bar" if desired.
- Use autolayout for the UITableView (not springs and struts) and pin the top of the table to the top of the VC's view.
- Add this delegate method:

`- (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id<UIBarPositioning>)bar {
  return UIBarPositionTopAttached;
}`

DON'T:

- Fiddle with edgesForExtendedLayout
- Fiddle with extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars
- Fiddle with the table's contentInset

Answer (score 3):

Basically this is due to the traslucency of the nav bar, usually the view controller fix that overlapping, by correcting the top insets of the owned view or subview if they are(or inherits) from UIScrollView. You have 2 options, one is to set the traslucency of the navbar to no, the other is set the `edgeForExtendedLayout` to none ore leave only bottom.

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
}

- (void)searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}
```

These advices works only on iOS7, if you are deploying on lower target check before settings those properties.
Another way around, but I didn't tested could be read the `--topLayoutGuide` length and in the -`searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch` try to set a topInsets of the same length. In this way you should still preserve the translucency.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem as the OP, but I am not showing a NavBar.  This is in a navigation controller that I segue to as a modal popup.  As I am not showing a NavBar, setting the translucency does not fix the problem.

Comment: Try with edgesForExtendedLayout

Comment: more probably also .. `-setAutomaticallyAdjustScrollInsets`

Comment: Unfortunately neither of those helped. I wound up using a navigation bar.

Answer (score 3):

I have UISearchBar and UISearchDisplayController.

In viewdidload:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
[searchDisplayController.searchBar setBackgroundImage:[self imageWithColor:ETSBaseColor] forBarPosition:0 barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

method that obtain image from UIColor:

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem:

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
    controller.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleDefault; // Used to cover UIStatusBar
}

- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
    controller.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal; // Used not to show top and bottom separator lines
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I don't want to hide the UINavigationBar but I had similar problems with gapes and other side effects. One of them was a missing UISearchBar after switching between UIViewControllers while the UISearchDisplayController is visible (I'm using SWRevealViewController to switch between UIViewController). This problem occurs only on iPads. It came out that the UISearchBar suddenly hides behind the UINavigationBar. Now I solved all my Problems with the following lines of code in the UITableViewController which is presented in a UIContainerView:

```
- (UINavigationController *)navigationController {
    return nil;
}
```

Those lines prevent the UISearchDisplayController to reach and change my UINavigationController. I also subclassed this method into "MyContainerTableViewController" class and use this class now for all embedded UITableViewController.

I'm still using UISearchDisplayController to Support iOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

The following hack worked for me:

```objective-c
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return (self.searchController.isActive  && section == 0) ? 22.0f : 0.0f;
}
```