# UISearchController does not cover status bar with opaque UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have researched this problem a lot but I have found no solution that would work for me.

Basically, I have a `UIViewController` that presents `UISearchController` like this:

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.delegate = self
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
view.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
```

User is then expected to tap the `UISearchBar` to present `searchController` and reveal the keyboard. However, a strange thing happens during the transition between controllers.

[image: Overlap]

It seems as if the `UISearchController` didn't cover the status bar and let you see the `UIViewController` that presented it below. *I would like to find a way to prevent this, i.e. to force the search controller to extend all the way under the status bar.*

Things that I have already done:

- I have set `self.definesPresentationContext = true` in `viewDidLoad:`.
- I have found out that this is a known bug, namely rdar://20942583.
- I have attempted to circumvent the bug by setting:

  ```
  self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .All
  self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
  ```

  It didn't work.

I'm running out of ideas. Please help.

Thanks a bunch,
Pete.

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issue and tried everything from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23124853/uitableview-content-overlaps-status-bar-when-uisearchbar-is-active) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32687240/ios-9-searchbar-disappears-from-table-header-view-when-uisearchcontroller-is-act) and none of this worked for me :(

Best workaround that is working (ugly I know) until I find a better solution:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchController.delegate = self
}

func willPresentSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

    let statusHeight = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height

    if bgBar == nil {
        bgBar = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.width, (navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)! + statusHeight))
        bgBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        view.addSubview(bgBar)
    } else {
        bgBar.hidden = false
    }

    tableView.contentInset.top = statusHeight
}

func willDismissSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

    bgBar.hidden = true
    tableView.contentInset.top = 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On swift 4:

```
viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   let statusHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height
   let sbview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: statusHeight))
   sbview.backgroundColor = .white
   view.addSubview(sbview)
{
```